# How do I get my application to run with administrator rights automatically?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, manifest

I've made a console application that is supposed to update some registry entries so that I can access 32 bit COM components from a 64 bit application.  If I have admin rights, it works great, but I can't seem to get the application run with admin rights out of the box.

This is what I've done.

1. Create a Windows Console Application.
2. Add my code.
3. Right click on my project and select Properties.
4. Navigate to `Configuration Properties > Linker > Manifest File > UAC Execution Level` and set to `requireAdministrator (/level='requireAdministrator')`.

[image]

It took a lot to figure out this because all of the info on the web is for Visual Studio 2010 or earlier which required manually creating an XML manifest file and conflicts with the auto generated one  that this creates.

However, this doesn't seem to be enough to get it to run as an admin.  It is a real PITA that this information isn't made easily findable.  Is there some other step that I am missing?  Something like a signing process?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is how this mini application is run.

From my main programme, using `ShellExecute()` or `ShellExecuteEx()` with the `"runas"` verb will allow running of this executable with administrator privileges without popping up a UAC dialog.

Running this from the command line however, will result in this mini app being executed in the user's security context, which is what I was doing.